# fill option on html with java array list

Tags: java, html, jsf, bootstrap-4

i want to use multiple drop down select in JSF. here is the code that i found for this solution:

```
<select id="dates-field2" class="multiselect-ui form-control"
                                        multiple="multiple">
         <option value="item1" >item1</option>
         <option value="item2" >item2</option>

</select>
```

how can i use this in JSF page and fill options by array list in java instead of item1 and item2?
I'd used f:selectItems in JSF but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Your example is just plain HTML. If you want JSF to render this as its output you need to use the `h:selectManyListbox` tag. It also provides the possibility to pass a collection to it that renders all of the options.

```
<h:selectManyListbox value="#{yourSelectedItemValue}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{yourCollection}" var="f"
                itemLabel="#{f.yourItemLabel}" itemValue="#{f.yourItemValue}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

This will give you more info on how to use it:
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-multiple-select-listbox-example/

Comment: its like a list but i want to use it as drop down that can select multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you looking for **h:selectManyMenu** component? Is pretty similar to Ipper`s explanation:

```
<h:selectManyMenu value="#{yourBean.selectedValues}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{yourBean.yourCollection}" var="item"
        itemLabel="#{item.label}" itemValue="#{item.value}"/>
</h:selectManyMenu>
```